# In java, how come method read() from FileInputStream works does not throw " incompatible types: possible lossy conversion"?

Tags: java, io, stream, byte

I am currently going through Java I/O [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html) and having hard time understanding the read() method of FileInputStream class. I know that per documantion that read() method reads "byte" of data from stream and returns an integer representing the byte (between 0 and 256) or -1 if it reaches the end of file.

Byte in java has a range between -128 and 127, so, how come when I edit xanadu.txt and add ASCI symbol "ƒ" (which has a decimal value of 131), java does not complain by throwing an error that value 131 is out of range defined by byte (-128 and 127)? When I try to test this using literals I get two different results.

The following works:

```
byte b = 120;
int c = b;
System.out.println((char)c);

Output: x
```

But this does NOT work (even though it works when added to xanadu.txt):

```
byte b = 131;
int c = b;
System.out.println((char)c);

Output: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
        byte b = 131;
```

I tried explicitly casting using byte: (how is this possible?)

```
byte b = (byte)131;
int c = b;
System.out.println((char)c);

Output: ﾃ
```

I am total newbie when it comes to I/O streams, somebody please help me understand it.

EDIT: Turns out my knowledge on concepts of type casting was lacking, specifically in understanding the difference between "Widening" and "Narrowing". Reading up more about these concepts helped me understand why explicit (aka narrowing) casting works.

Allow me to explain: Look at the 3rd code block where I am explicitly casting the literal '131' to type of byte. If we are to convert the literal 131 into binary form of 32-bit signed 2's complement integer, we will get 00000000 00000000 00000000 10000011 which is 32-bits or 4 bytes. Recall that Java data type 'byte' can only hold 8-bit signed 2's complement integer, so, 131 is out of range and thus we get error "possible lossy conversion from int to byte". But, when we explicitly cast it to byte, we are 'chopping off' or correct term would be 'narrowing' the binary down to 8 bit integer. So, when we do that, then the resulting binary is 10000011 which is -125 in decimal value. Since -125 is in range of -128 and 127, byte has no issues accepting and storing it. Now when I try to story the value of byte in int c, implicit or "widening" casting takes place, where -125 in binary form of 8-bit 10000011 is converted into equivalent -125 in binary form of 32-bit 11111111 11111111 11111111 10000011. Finally, system.out is trying to output the value of (char)c which is another explicit or "narrowing" casting where its trying to shrink from 32-bit signed to 16-bit unsigned. When casting is complete, we get 11111111 10000011 in binary form. Now, when this binary is converted into character form by java, it returns ﾃ.

I can conclude by saying that it helps converting everything into binary form and go from there. But make sure you understand encoding and [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: Did you consider checking the encoding format of the file? A *byte* is not automatically a character. A character can be encoded by many bytes.

Comment: @akuzminykh, encoding of my file is ANSI.  "A character can be encoded by many bytes" - so does that mean ASCII extended character ƒ [Latin small letter f with hook] is stored as multiple bytes and not just 1 byte? If that is so, then it makes a lot more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you got the value 131 from, but as far as I am concerned, LATIN SMALL LETTER F WITH HOOK (ƒ) is not in the original ASCII character set, but in extended ASCII, with a decimal value of 159. See [here](http://www.asciitable.com). It is also encoded in UTF-16 (how Java `char`s are encoded) as hex 192 (decimal value 402).

First, ensure that your text files are encoded in extended ASCII, and not UTF-8 (which is the most likely encoding). Then you can use a `FileInputStream` to `read` the file, and you will get `159`.

Note that `159` is outside the range of the the Java `byte` type. This is fine, because `read` returns an `int`. If the text file is encoded in UTF-8 however, ƒ is encoded in 2 bytes, so `read` will be reading one byte at a time.

Your second code block doesn't work because as you said, `byte` goes from -128 to 127, so 131 obviously doesn't fit.

Your third code block forces 131 into a byte, which causes overflow and the value "wraps back around" to -125. `b` and `c` are both -125. When you cast this to a `char` it becomes 65411 because this conversion involves padding the whole number to 16-bits first, then treating it as an unsigned integer.

The reason why this all works when you use `FileInputStream.read` instead of doing these conversions yourself, is because `read` actually returns an `int`, not a `byte`. It's just that the `int` it returns will always be in the range -1 ~ 255. This is why we say "`read` returns a byte", but its actual return type is `int`.

Comment: I use ascii table listed [here](https://www.ascii-code.com/). I use notepad++, so texts are by default encoded in ANSI. Q2: "Note that 159 is outside the range of the Java byte type" - shouldn't Java throw the error that I am seeing when I try with literals "error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte"?  Q2: [..]If the text file is encoded in UTF-8 however, ƒ is encoded in 2 bytes, so read will be reading one byte at a time" - I am confused here, as you mentioned previously encoding should be in ASCII and not in UTF-8?

Comment: @PalonchiPismadonchi java doesn’t throw the error because `read` doesn’t return a `byte` at all. It returns an `int`. It returns an `int` exactly because numbers such as 159 doesn’t fit in a `byte`. And the character would be encoded as 2 bytes ***if*** the file is encoded in UTF-8. If you are sure that your file is in ASCII you can ignore the part about UTF-8.

Comment: I see. I had limited understanding of different types of encodings. My brain finally 'clicked'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
byte b = 131;  // this is 8 bits type, but >8 bits value
int c = b;     // this is 32 bits type
System.out.println((char)c);  // this is 16 bits type

Output: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
        byte b = 131;
```

The two-complement encoding of 131 is:

```
2^7+2^1+2^0
^^^
sign bit
```

131 won't fit in a *signed* byte without an overflow in the [two complement representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) that is used for signed types. The highest bit=sign bit is set which [gets extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Sign_extension) when casting from byte to int.

The Java compiler notices that 131 won't fit properly in a byte which leads to the error.

Comment: just  a little note: it is not a "warning", it is an "error" (code should not get compiled successfully)